# Egalitarian references in Chazal

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, reward-punishment, free-will-bechira, chazal

I'm trying to find references in Chazal to the principle that people are judged/rewarded based on the choices they make, regardless of their specific role in society.  For example, I believe I have seen a Tanna D'bei Eliyahu to that effect, as well as a statement from Rabbi Akiva(?) that an idolatrous gentile when studying Torah is greater than the Kohen Gadol (possibly in Sanhedrin).  Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Statement about gentile studying Torah is from R. Meir ([AZ 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.3a.2?with=all&lang=bi)). But see Tos. there.

Comment: Note the conclusion גדול מצווה ועושה

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79166/16706

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16615/16706 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29843/16706 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35058/16706

Comment: משנה סנהדרין דקה.ומפני שלום הברייות, שלא יאמר אדם לחברו, אבא גדול מאביך.

Comment: Maybe the last mishna in menachot

Comment: Rambam ([*Hil. 'Avadim* 9:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=12&hilchos=73&perek=9&halocha=8)), in explaining why a person should be respectful and attentive towards a servant's concerns (whether a Jewish or non-Jewish servant), cites [*Iyov* 31:13,15](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2731.htm#13): "Shall I despise the petition of my manservant or maidservant when they contend with me? ... Didn't the One who made me in the belly, make him, and fashion us in like womb?"

Answer (score 5):

מעיד אני עלי את השמים ואת הארץ, בין ישראל בין עכו״ם, בין איש בין אשה, בין עבד ובין שפחה הכל לפי מעשה שהוא עושה - כך רוח הקודש שורה עליו.
([Seder Eliyahu Raba 9](https://www.sefaria.org/Tanna_Debei_Eliyahu_Rabbah.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). 
And [Avoda Zara 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.3a.2?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) (Rabbi Meir). See also [Rambam, end of Shmita ve-Yovel](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=7&hilchos=40&perek=13&halocha=13&hilite=).

Comment: What is seder Eliyahu?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel: Tanna deVei Eliyahu has two parts -- Seder Eliyahu Rabbah, and , Seder Eliyahu Zuta (the big and little Orders of Eliyahu, respectively). The transmission was described in the gemara https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.106a.2-3 , although the version we have is probably from the end of the geonim or so. (Ch. 2 says that 4700 AM passed already.) R Anan, whom Eliyahu taught the original version of these beraisos was a talmid of Shemuel, so I would place him as early 3rd cent CE.

Comment: Thank you for this. Will be sharing on Facebook after work.

Answer (score 4):

> **הוריות יג.** כהן קודם ללוי לוי לישראל ישראל לממזר וממזר לנתין ונתין לגר וגר לעבד משוחרר אימתי בזמן שכולם שוים אבל אם היה ממזר תלמיד חכם וכהן גדול עם הארץ ממזר תלמיד חכם קודם לכהן גדול עם הארץ
>
> Horiyos 13a: Kohen before a levi. Levi before a yisroel. Yisroel before a mamzer. Mamzer before a nasin [Gibeonite]. Nasin before a convert. Convert before a freed slave. When? When they are all equal [in deeds], but if the mamzer is a Torah scholar and the Kohen Gadol is an ignoramus, the mamzer Torah scholar precedes the Kohen Gadol ignoramus.

Answer (score 4):

[Bava Kama 38a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma_38a.11)

> ולא והתניא ר"מ אומר מנין שאפילו נכרי ועוסק בתורה שהוא ככהן גדול ת"ל (ויקרא יח, ה) אשר יעשה אותם האדם וחי בהם כהנים ולוים וישראלים לא נאמר אלא אדם הא למדת שאפילו נכרי ועוסק בתורה הרי הוא ככהן גדול
>
> The Gemara asks: But do they not receive reward for fulfilling those mitzvot? But isn’t it taught in a baraita that Rabbi Meir says: From where is it derived that even a gentile who engages in Torah is considered like a High Priest? The verse states with regard to the mitzvot: “Which if a person does, he shall live by them” (Leviticus 18:5). It is not stated: Which if priests and Levites and Israelites do, they shall live by them, but rather: A person, indicating that all people are included. You have therefore learned that even a gentile who engages in Torah study is considered like a High Priest.

[Menachos 29a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot_29b.11)

> ומפני מה נברא העולם הזה בה"י מפני שדומה לאכסדרה שכל הרוצה לצאת יצא ומ"ט תליא כרעיה דאי הדר בתשובה מעיילי ליה
>
> And for what reason was this world created specifically with the letter heh? It is because the letter heh, which is open on its bottom, has a similar appearance to a portico, which is open on one side. And it alludes to this world, where anyone who wishes to leave may leave, i.e., every person has the ability to choose to do evil. And what is the reason that the left leg of the letter heh is suspended, i.e., is not joined to the roof of the letter? It is because if one repents, he is brought back in through the opening at the top.

[Berachos 33b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot_33b.23)

> ואמר רבי חנינא הכל בידי שמים חוץ מיראת שמים שנאמר ועתה ישראל מה ה׳ אלהיך שואל מעמך כי אם ליראה
>
> Tangentially, the Gemara cites an additional statement by Rabbi Ḥanina concerning principles of faith. And Rabbi Ḥanina said: Everything is in the hands of Heaven, except for fear of Heaven. Man has free will to serve God or not, as it is stated: “And now Israel, what does the Lord your God ask of you other than to fear the Lord your God, to walk in all of His ways, to love Him and to serve the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul” (Deuteronomy 10:12). The Lord asks man to perform these matters because ultimately, the choice is in his hands.

Nida 16b

> דדריש ר' חנינא בר פפא אותו מלאך הממונה על ההריון לילה שמו ונוטל טפה ומעמידה לפני הקב''ה ואומר לפניו רבש''ע טפה זו מה תהא עליה גבור או חלש חכם או טיפש עשיר או עני ואילו רשע או צדיק לא קאמר כדר' חנינא דא''ר חנינא הכל בידי שמים חוץ מיראת שמים שנאמר ועתה ישראל מה ה' אלהיך שואל מעמך כי אם ליראה

[Devarim Rabbah 4:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Devarim_Rabbah.4.3)

> דָּבָר אַחֵר, רְאֵה אָנֹכִי אָמַר רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר מִשֶּׁאָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא הַדָּבָר הַזֶּה בְּסִינַי, בְּאוֹתָהּ שָׁעָה (איכה ג, לח): מִפִּי עֶלְיוֹן לֹא תֵצֵא הָרָעוֹת וְהַטּוֹב, אֶלָּא מֵאֵלֶיהָ הָרָעָה בָּאָה עַל עוֹשֵׂי הָרָעָה, וְהַטּוֹבָה בָּאָה עַל עוֹשֵׂי הַטּוֹבָה. דָּבָר אַחֵר, אָמַר רַבִּי חַגַּי וְלֹא עוֹד שֶׁנָּתַתִּי לָכֶם שְׁתֵּי דְרָכִים, אֶלָּא שֶׁנִּכְנַסְתִּי לִפְנִים מִשּׁוּרַת הַדִּין וְאָמַרְתִּי לָכֶם (דברים ל, יט): וּבָחַרְתָּ בַּחַיִּים.

[Eichah Rabbah 3:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Eichah_Rabbah.3.13)

> מִי זֶה אָמַר וַתֶּהִי ה' לֹא צִוָּה, מִי צִוָּה, הָמָן צִוָּה, וְהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לֹא צִוָּה, הָמָן צִוָּה לְהַשְּׁמִיד לַהֲרֹג וּלְאַבֵּד, וְהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לֹא צִוָּה, אֶלָּא (אסתר ט, כה): יָשׁוּב מַחֲשַׁבְתּוֹ וגו'. מִפִּי עֶלְיוֹן לֹא תֵצֵא הָרָעוֹת וְהַטּוֹב, אָמַר רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר מִשָּׁעָה שֶׁאָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא (דברים ל, טו): רְאֵה נָתַתִּי לְפָנֶיךָ הַיּוֹם אֶת הַחַיִּים וְאֶת הַטּוֹב וְאֶת הַמָּוֶת וְאֶת הָרָע, לֹא יָצָאת טוֹבָה לְעוֹשֵׂה רָעָה, וְרָעָה לְעוֹשֵׂה טוֹבָה, אֶלָּא טוֹבָה לְעוֹשֵׂה טוֹבָה וְרָעָה לְעוֹשֵׂה רָעָה, כְּמָה דְאַתְּ אָמַר (שמואל ב ג, לט): יְשַׁלֵּם ה' לְעֹשֵׂה הָרָעָה כְּרָעָתוֹ. מַה יִּתְאוֹנֵן אָדָם חָי, דַּיּוֹ שֶׁהוּא חַי, אָמַר רַבִּי לֵוִי אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא חַיּוּתְךָ בְּיָדִי וָחַי, וְאַתָּה מִתְאוֹנֵן.  אָמַר רַבִּי הוּנָא יַעֲמֹד כְּגִבּוֹר וְיוֹדֶה עַל חֲטָאָיו וְאַל יִתְאוֹנֵן.  אָמַר רַבִּי בֶּרֶכְיָה מַה יִּתְאוֹנֵן עַל חֵי הָעוֹלָמִים, אִם מְבַקֵּשׁ הוּא לְהִתְאוֹנֵן גֶּבֶר עַל חֲטָאָו. רַבִּי אוֹמֵר בְּנֵי תּוּרְעֲמָנִין, אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן אַחַר כָּל הַשֶּׁבַח שֶׁעָשִׂיתִי עִמּוֹ הוּא מִתְרַעֵם לְפָנַי וְאוֹמֵר (בראשית ג, יב): הָאִשָּׁה אֲשֶׁר נָתַתָּ עִמָּדִי. אַף יַעֲקֹב כֵּן, אֲנִי עוֹסֵק לְהַמְלִיךְ אֶת בְּנוֹ בְּמִצְרַיִם וְהוּא מִתְרַעֵם וְאוֹמֵר (ישעיה מ, כז): נִסְתְּרָה דַרְכִּי מֵה'. וְאַף בָּנָיו כֵּן, אֲנִי עוֹסֵק לָבוּר לָהֶם לֶחֶם קַל כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹא יְהֵא אֶחָד מֵהֶן גּוֹסֵא וְדוּלַרְיָיא אוֹחַזְתּוֹ, וְהֵן מִתְרַעֲמִין לְפָנַי וְאוֹמְרִים (במדבר כא, ה): וְנַפְשֵׁנוּ קָצָה בַּלֶּחֶם הַקְּלֹקֵל. אַף צִיּוֹן כֵּן הִיא (ישעיה מט, יד): וַתֹּאמֶר צִיּוֹן עֲזָבַנִי ה' וַה' שְׁכֵחָנִי.

[Tanchuma, Reay 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma,_Re%27eh.3.1)

> דָּבָר אַחֵר, רְאֵה אָנֹכִי וְגוֹ'. זֶה שֶׁאָמַר הַכָּתוּב: מִפִּי עֶלְיוֹן לֹא תֵּצֵא הָרָעוֹת וְהַטּוֹב (איכה ג, לח). אָמַר רַבִּי אָבִין, בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁעָמְדוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל לִפְנֵי הַר סִינַי, נָתַן לָהֶם הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אֶת הַתּוֹרָה, בְּאוֹתָהּ שָׁעָה כָּל מִי שֶׁחָטָא הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא פּוֹרֵעַ מִמֶּנּוּ. לְשֶׁעָבַר כָּל מִי שֶׁחוֹטֵא, הָיָה דּוֹר מְשַׁלֵּם חֶטְאוֹ. לְדוֹר הַמַּבּוּל, אָמְרוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ: הַרְבֵּה כְּשֵׁרִים הָיוּ בָּהֶן כְּגוֹן נֹחַ וְנִמְחוּ עִם הַדּוֹר. בְּדוֹר הַפְלָגָה הָיוּ חוֹטְאִין, אֲפִלּוּ הַתִּינוֹקוֹת מִשְׁתַּלְּמִין. כְּשֶׁעָמְדוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּסִינַי וְנָתַן לָהֶם הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אֶת הַמִּצְוֹת, אָמַר, לְשֶׁעָבַר הָיוּ הַדּוֹרוֹת לוֹקִין עַל עָוֹן שֶׁל אֶחָד מֵהֶן. מִכָּאן וָאֵילָךְ, אֵין הַדּוֹר לוֹקֶה עַל אֶחָד. הֱוֵי, מִפִּי עֶלְיוֹן לֹא תֵּצֵא הָרָעוֹת וְהַטּוֹב. וְאָמַר רַבִּי אָבִין, הַמִּקְרָא הַזֶּה מַתְמִיהַּ, מִפִּי עֶלְיוֹן לֹא תֵּצֵא, לֹא רָעוֹת לַצַּדִּיקִים, וְלֹא טוֹבוֹת לָרְשָׁעִים. אַף מֹשֶׁה סִדֵּר לִפְנֵיהֶם שְׁנֵי דְּרָכִים, הַטּוֹבָה וְהָרָעָה, דֶּרֶךְ חַיִּים וְדֶרֶךְ מָוֶת, בְּרָכָה וּקְלָלָה, שֶׁלֹּא יִהְיוּ הָרְשָׁעִים אוֹמְרִים: בָּרָא אֶת הָעוֹלָם סְתָם, וְלֹא פֵּרֵשׁ לָנוּ אֵיזֶה דֶּרֶךְ טוֹבָה, וְאֵיזוֹ דֶּרֶךְ רָעָה שֶׁנִּפְרֹשׁ מִמֶּנָּה וְנָבֹא לַטּוֹבָה. לְכָךְ אָמַר לָהֶם מֹשֶׁה, וְהַבְּרָכָה אִם תִּשְׁמְעוּ, וְהַקְּלָלָה אִם לֹא תִּשְׁמְעוּ. מָשָׁל לְזָקֵן שֶׁהָיָה יוֹשֵׁב עַל הַדֶּרֶךְ, וְהָיוּ לְפָנָיו שְׁתֵּי דְּרָכִים, אַחַת תְּחִלָּתָהּ קוֹצִים וְסוֹפָהּ מִישׁוֹר, וְאַחַת תְּחִלָּתָהּ מִישׁוֹר וְסוֹפָהּ קוֹצִים, וְהָיָה יוֹשֵׁב בְּרֹאשׁ שְׁתֵּיהֶן וּמַזְהִיר הָעוֹבְרִים, וְאוֹמֵר לָהֶם, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאַתֶּם רוֹאִים תְּחִלָּתָהּ שֶׁל זוֹ קוֹצִים, לְכוּ בָּהּ, שֶׁסּוֹפָהּ מִישׁוֹר. וְכָל מִי שֶׁהָיָה חָכָם שׁוֹמֵעַ לוֹ וְהָיָה מְהַלֵּךְ בָּהּ וּמִתְיַגֵּעַ קִמְעָא. הָלַךְ בְּשָׁלוֹם וּבָא בְּשָׁלוֹם. אֲבָל אוֹתָן שֶׁלֹּא הָיוּ שׁוֹמְעִין לוֹ, הָיוּ הוֹלְכִים וְנִכְשָׁלִין בַּסּוֹף. כָּךְ הָיָה מֹשֶׁה, פֵּרֵשׁ לִבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְאָמַר לָהֶם: הֲרֵי דֶּרֶךְ הַחַיִּים וְדֶרֶךְ הַמָּוֶת, בְּרָכָה וּקְלָלָה, וּבָחַרְתָּ בַּחַיִּים לְמַעַן תִּחְיֶה אַתָּה וְזַרְעֶךָ.
>
> Another interpretation: "See I, etc," (Deuteronomy 11:26). This is that which the verse stated (Lamentations 3:38), "Is it not at the word of the Most High, that weal and woe befall?" At the time that Israel stood in front of Mount Sinai, the Holy One, blessed be He, gave them the Torah. At that time, the Holy One, blessed be He, took remuneration from every [individual] that sinned. In the past the generation would pay for the sin of anyone who sinned. Our rabbis said about the generation of the Flood, "There were many among them that were proper as much as Noach, and they were erased with the generation." In the generation of [the Tower of Babel], when they sinned, the infants were charged. [But] from when Israel stood at Sinai and the Holy One, blessed be He gave them the commandments, He said, "In the past, the generations were punished for each of their [individuals]. [But] from now on, a generation will not be punished for an [individual]." Hence, "Is it not at the word of the Most High, that weal and woe befall?"

See Yad, Teshuvah 5:2

Comment: Also in Sanhedrin

Comment: That's a bit vague. What of your quotes are also in Sanhedrin, and where?

Comment: @MichaBerger oh, it was just on the first one which OP seeks.

Answer (score 1):

Not only the tribe of Levi, but any man of all the inhabitants of the earth, whose spirit has moved him and whose mind has given him to understand to set himself aside to stand before G‑d to serve Him, to worship Him, to know G‑d and walk justly as G‑d has created him, and he cast from his neck the yoke of the many calculations that men seek — this man has become sanctified, a holy of holies, and G‑d shall be his portion and his lot forever, and shall grant him his needs in this world, as He has granted the Kohanim and the Levites... (Mishneh Torah, Laws of the Shemittah and Jubilee Cycles, 13:13)"

Comment: Is this Chazal?

Comment: Just adding the English text that wfb brings above as a link: See also Rambam, end of Shmita ve-Yovel.

Comment: I referenced Rambam in Teshuva 5, but I didn’t think that OP was looking for texts that recent.